# pytest mark django db: avoid to save fixture in tests

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I need to:

1. Avoid to use save() in tests
2. Use @pytest.mark.django_db on all tests inside this class
3. Create a number of trx fixtures (10/20) to act like false data.

```py
import pytest

from ngg.processing import (
    elab_data
)


class TestProcessing:

    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_elab_data(self, plan, 
                             obp, 
                             customer, 
                             bac, 
                             col,
                             trx_1,
                             trx_2,
                             ...):
        
        plan.save()
        obp.save()
        customer.save()
        bac.save()
        col.save()
        trx.save()

        elab_data(bac, col)
```

Where the fixtures are simply models like that:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def plan():
    plan = Plan(
        name = 'test_plan',
        status = '1'
    )
    return plan
```

I don't find this way really clean. How would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

test.py

```
import pytest

from ngg.processing import elab_data


@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestProcessing:

    def test_elab_data(self, plan, obp, customer, bac, col, trx_1, trx_2):
        elab_data(bac, col)
```

conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[
    ('test_plan', 1),
    ('test_plan2', 2),
])
def plan(request, db):
    name, status = request.param
    return Plan.objects.create(name=name, status=status)
```

I'm not quite sure if I got it correctly

1. *Avoid to use save() in tests*

You may create objects using `instance = Model.objects.create()` or just put `instance.save()` in fixtures.

As described at note section [here](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#pytest.mark.django_db)

> To access the database in a fixture, it is recommended that the fixture explicitly request one of the db, transactional_db or django_db_reset_sequences fixtures.

and at fixture section [here](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#db)

> This fixture will ensure the Django database is set up. Only required for fixtures that want to use the database themselves. A test function should normally use the pytest.mark.django_db() mark to signal it needs the database.

you may want to use `db` fixture in you records fixtures and keep `django_db` mark in your test cases.

2. *Use @pytest.mark.django_db on all tests inside this class*

To mark whole classes you may use decorator on classes or `pytestmark` variable as described [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/markers.html#marking-whole-classes-or-modules).

> You may use pytest.mark decorators with classes to apply markers to all of its test methods

> To apply marks at the module level, use the pytestmark global variable

3. *Create a number of trx fixtures (10/20) to act like false data.*

I didn't quite get what you were trying to do but still would assume that it is one of the following things:

**Create multiple objects and pass them as fixtures**

In that case you may want to create a fixture that will return generator or list and use whole list instead of multiple fixtures

**Test case using different variants of fixture but with one/few at a time**

In that case you may want to [parametrize](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#parametrizing-fixtures) your fixture so it will return different objects and test case will run multiple times - one time per one variant

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!